# Range over posts in nested section in hugo

Tags: go, hugo, hugo-content-organization

I use this code to show related posts in the same sections for posts in `/content/posts`. However, the code stops working when I move the content to a nested section, such as `content/posts/news`, resulting in content from other sections appearing. Could anyone provide a solution or guide me on how to make this work?

```
{{ range where (where site.RegularPages "Section" .Section) "Permalink" "ne" .Permalink }}
  <a href="{{ .RelPermalink }}">{{ .LinkTitle }}</a>
{{ end }}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using [`.CurrentSection.Pages`](https://gohugo.io/content-management/sections/#section-page-variables-and-methods), which is better fit for this than filtering all the results from `site.RegularPages`.

Then the current page can also be filtered out with a simple `where` statement.

```html
{{ range (where .CurrentSection.Pages "Permalink" "ne" .Permalink) }}
    <a href="{{ .RelPermalink }}">{{ .LinkTitle }}</a>
{{ end }}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).